# Codeigniter Error | Class "file" not found SYSTEMPATH\Config\Services.php at line 667

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i have got this error, in codeigniter 4.

this message i got from my log with **"critical"** level.

```
Class "file" not found

                                        
in SYSTEMPATH\Config\Services.php on line 667.
 1 SYSTEMPATH\Config\BaseService.php(252): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session(Object(Config\App), false)
 2 SYSTEMPATH\Config\BaseService.php(193): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('session', [...])
 3 SYSTEMPATH\Config\Services.php(641): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::getSharedInstance('session', null)
 4 SYSTEMPATH\Config\BaseService.php(252): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session()
 5 SYSTEMPATH\Common.php(988): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('session', [])
 6 APPPATH\Filters\UsersAuthFilter.php(13): session()
 7 SYSTEMPATH\Filters\Filters.php(173): App\Filters\UsersAuthFilter->before(Object(CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest), null)
 8 SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php(473): CodeIgniter\Filters\Filters->run('/', 'before')
 9 SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php(368): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(null, Object(Config\Cache), false)
10 FCPATH\index.php(67): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
```

this is the error looklike
[error screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQAnu.png).
When i get this error, i just refresh 1 or more and then the application running well.
this happen only on server.
this error can happen more than 20 times in a day.

durring my development in my local i never get this message.

im confuse where is the problem. can someone help me pls.

i want to track the problem and solve this problem.

Comment: Could you post `APPPATH\Filters\UsersAuthFilter.php(13)`?

Comment: And your `Session.php`-config? Furthermore what are your servers permssions on the writable folder?